# Try to hide header on login page but did not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hide my header component on login page like following. But this is not working. Please guide how I can do this. Thanks in advance!

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var auth = localStorage.getItem("auth")
    console.log("app ===>", auth)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <LinkBar />
          <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/home">
                <Protected cmp={Home}></Protected>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/shopping">
                <Protected cmp={Products}></Protected>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/login">
                <Login />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: you can put a ternary and check if auth exists and then render it, otherwise render null

example : auth ? <Header /> : ' ';

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should work with jsx.

```
 { auth ? <Header auth={auth}></Header> : null }
```

or more elegant way

```
 { auth && (<Header auth={auth}></Header>) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like bellow:

```
function App(){
   return(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
         <Route component={DefaultContainer} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
   );
}


const DefaultContainer = () => (
  <Header />
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/shopping" component={Shopping} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```